# How to stop LLDB when error occurs

Tags: c++, macos, pyinstaller, lldb

I want to improve the already good analysis of the PyInstaller issue https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2355. For that I need to either catch all errors or set a specific break point with LLDB.

On GitHub [I stated](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2355#issuecomment-277482916)

> For starters one would essentially just need a break point that catches all errors and then dump the call stack.
>   I tried `break set -E C++`, `breakpoint set --selector __cxa_throw:` [...] but nope, doesn't stop.

The execution *does* stop i.e. hit the break point [if I do `b Get`](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2355#issuecomment-277486103) but there are way too many functions this selector affects.

To conclude, how can I make the executable, available at http://frightanic.com/misc/hello-world, stop right when that error at `./src/common/stdpbase.cpp(62)` occurs?

Answer (score 0):

`--selector` specifies a break on an ObjC selector name.  So I wouldn't expect that one to work.  I don't know how these check macros work, but the one getting tripped says it returns a value in non-debug or stops in the debugger  for debug, so I'd be surprised if it throws a C++ exception.  The fact that the C++ exception breakpoint isn't getting tripped bears that out.  You can specify a class::method to lldb's breakpoint.  So you might try:

```
(lldb) break set -n wxStandardPathsBase::Get
```

That should narrow the breakpoint down.  Of course if you have debug information for the wxwidgets, you should be able to set a file & line breakpoint which will also be more precise.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Your suggested break point apparently isn't correct though, execution isn't stopped. I'm really puzzled...it just _ought_ to work. I don't know how exactly PyInstaller arrives at the binary it produces. Can you derive anything from the binary I linked in the question?

Comment: That binary looks like it has been stripped.  It doesn't link to anything that looks like wxWhatever, so I presume that stuff has been statically linked into the hello world binary, but then the symbol table has been stripped.  The tool "nm" will show you the symbols, if you want to see for yourself.  At some point in the build there was an unstripped binary, that still had symbols the debugger could break on.  You want to debug that stage not the post-strip binary.

Comment: I considered this early in my analysis (didn't know about `nm` though) but according to http://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html the symbol-table is only stripped if you pass `--strip` to PyInstaller or have `strip=True` in the `.spec` file. I don't doubt your analysis but I'm puzzled. Will continue searching...

Comment: Furthermore, how can I be told that the execution failed at `./src/common/stdpbase.cpp(62)` if on the other hand the symbol-table is missing? What's the correlation between the two?

Comment: The code in question probably uses the `__FILE__` etc macros when it goes to print the error.  Those bake the file/function/line number into the actual code just like any other static string data.